# spin_unlock successful without spin_lock in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, concurrency, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I wrote a basic kernel code to check whether i can just call spin_unlock from other kernel control path without calling spin_lock and it worked.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
spinlock_t *my_lock;
struct task_struct *mythread;

static int threadfn(void *data)
{
    pr_info("Kernel thread running on processor:%d\n", smp_processor_id());
    msleep(1000);
    pr_info("Kernel thread unlocking without calling lock on processor:%d\n", smp_processor_id());
    spin_unlock(my_lock);
    return 0;
}

static int __init test_hello_init(void)
{
    my_lock = kmalloc(sizeof(spinlock_t), GFP_KERNEL);
    spin_lock_init(my_lock);
    pr_info("Init function running on processor:%d\n", smp_processor_id());
    spin_lock(my_lock);
    pr_info("Init function locked once on processor:%d\n", smp_processor_id());
    mythread = kthread_run(threadfn, NULL, "mythread");
    pr_info("Init function starting kernel thread\n");
    pr_info("Init function trying to lock twice on processor:%d\n", smp_processor_id());
    spin_lock(my_lock);
    pr_info("Init function locked on processor:%d\n", smp_processor_id());
    spin_unlock(my_lock);
    pr_info("Init function unlocked on processor:%d\n", smp_processor_id());
    kfree(my_lock);
    return -1;
}

static void __exit test_hello_exit(void)
{
}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);
```

Does this mean, there is no ownership in spinlocks?

Comment: If you turn lockdep and the other lock-related debugging checks on I bet you get an error.

Comment: "Does this mean, there is no ownership in spinlocks?" - This means that implementation of locks doesn't check all preconditions. If you want to know, whether some use case is allowed or not, you need to read a documentation, not to try to run a code.